# Do dict keys using list() to copy the same list produce a reference to one another?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I seem to be having an issue where I'm copying one template list to multiple keys in a `dict` using `list()` so that I can alter values specifically for a given list accessed with a `dict` key. However, I seem to be manipulating values across the keys for the copied list.

```
list1 = [['x', 'y', 0],
        ['m', 'n', 0],
]

dict2 = {'first': list(list1),
        'second': list(list1),
}

def attempt(arg):
    dict_key = dict2[arg]
    for each in dict_key:
        each[2] += 1

attempt('first')
print dict2['first']
print dict2['second']
```

Output:

```
[['x', 'y', 1], ['m', 'n', 1]] # expect elems to contain 1 
[['x', 'y', 1], ['m', 'n', 1]] # expect elems to contain 2
```

It would seem that the list() is actually not creating an actual copy, but behaving more like an assignment but this doesn't make sense to me. Can someone please explain?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: It's not at all clear from the questions that they're asking the same thing… but from the answers it is. And your answer there is great. Shame that question isn't as nice as this one, but I suppose it's probably best to close as a dup anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list()` does make a copy… but it's a *shallow* copy. When you call `a = list(b)`, a is a brand-new list, but it's referring to the same objects as `b`. If those objects are themselves lists, then you haven't done what you wanted to.

To do a "2-level" copy, you can just use a list comprehension:

```
a = [list(x) for x in b]
```

To do a all-the-way-down copy (which also takes care of tricky cases, like strings being made up of strings), use the [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function in the stdlib.

---

For debugging these kinds of things, it helps to use the `is` operator or the `id` function. For example:

```
>>> list1 = [['x', 'y', 0],
...         ['m', 'n', 0],
... ]
>>> dict2 = {'first': list(list1),
...         'second': list(list1),
... }
>>> id(dict2['first'])
4398414856
>>> id(dict2['second'])
4398414920
>>> id(dict2['first'][0])
4378407688
>>> id(dict2['second'][0])
4378407688
```

You can easily see that `first` and `second` are two different lists… but they have the same first element.

---

Or, alternatively, run your code in an interactive visualizer, like [this one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1+%3D+%5B%5B%27x%27,+%27y%27,+0%5D,%0A++++++++%5B%27m%27,+%27n%27,+0%5D,%0A%5D%0A%0Adict2+%3D+%7B%27first%27%3A+list%28list1%29,%0A++++++++%27second%27%3A+list%28list1%29,%0A%7D&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=4).

Comment: You can confirm this by: `print id(dict2['first']), id(dict2['second']);
print id(dict2['first'][0]), id(dict2['second'][0]);`

Comment: @Christian: I was in the middle of editing that into the answer; +1 for getting there first.

Comment: thanks @abarnert for the visualizer tip. That's really neat, bookmarked.